# Selecting a substring from a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am looking to find a string with in a string.

Lets say I have 2 strings:

```
String1 = "1.1)The Element is"

String2 = "1.1)The Element is:(-) for the sub"
```

If I compare String1 with String2, I can get **"1.1)The Element is"** which is ok.

```
 int Length_Str1 = string1.Length;

 string2 = string2.Remove(Length_Str1);
```

But I also want to get the non-alphabetical characters ":(-)". I am thinking to keep extracting the character until a space character is found. But I don't know how I can do it in C#.

Comment: So basically, you want to get `1.1)The Element is:(-)`?

Comment: You probably want to look at string.Substring

Comment: @Tijesunimi yes. But this is only 1 Example I have more strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take chars so long as `Char.IsLetter` and `Char.IsWhiteSpace` return `false`:

```
int index = String2.IndexOf(String1);
if(index >= 0)
{
    string result = String1;
    if (String1.Length < String2.Length)
    {
        string rest = String2.Substring(index + String1.Length);
        var chars = rest.TakeWhile(c => !Char.IsLetter(c) && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
        result = result + string.Join("", chars);
    }
}
```

Note that you have to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file.

Comment: I am having an error on this line,   var takeChars = rest.Where(c => !Char.IsLetter(c) && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c));                              The Error is: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Func<char,int,bool>' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @Kami: i have tested it with your sample strings. What framework version are you using, have you added `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: Yes I added the library. But let me check again.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
string s = "1.1)The Element is:(-) for the sub";
s = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("(-) ") + "(-) ".Length);
```

This gives `1.1)The Element is:(-)`

```
string s = "1.1)The Element is:(-) for the sub";
s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("(-) ") + "(-) ".Length);
```

This gives `for the sub`. Going by your comment:

```
 string String1 = "1.1)The Element is";

 string String2 = "1.1)The Element is:(-) for the sub";
 if(String2.Contains(String1))
 {
      string s = String2.Substring(String2.IndexOf(String1)+ String1.Length);
      s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(" ")+1);  // +1 to leave space
 }
```

Comment: Its not always the case, some strings contains "(-)". Some contains ")" Some contains ":" and some contains "-". I need some how to keep getting the characters until a space is found.

Comment: Your logic is flawed - the space is even after `the`, `element`, etc - how do you plan to differentiate them?

Comment: it should starting finding the space once the matching is found.

Comment: Matching for what is found?

Comment: match string1 with string2, matching is found now find the first space after the matching string.

Comment: See my edit - i think that is what youre looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
var String1 = "1.1)The Element is";
var String2 = "1.1)The Element is:(-) for the sub";
var result = string.Empty;
if(String2.Contains(String1))
{
    result = String1 + Regex.Match(String2.Replace(String1, string.Empty), "[^\\sa-zA-Z0-9]+").ToString();
}

//result will contain String1 + ":(-)" from String2 IF there is a match
```

Comment: +1 for having the same idea as mine, at least your answer is quicker lol. I spent way too much time to explain everything... :(

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved with a regular expression quite easily:

```
//Note the special escape character here for the regex engine not to fail on a found ')'
string string1 = @"1.1\)The Element is:";

List<string> testStrings = new List<string>();
testStrings.Add(@"1.1)The Element is:(-) for the sub 1");
testStrings.Add(@"1.1)The Element is:) for the sub 2");
testStrings.Add(@"1.1)The Element is:[-] for the sub 3");

//Create a regular expression string based upon the 'string1' provided above.
string regularExpression = string.Format(@"(?<base>{0})+(?:[^\\sa-zA-Z0-9]+)", string1);
Regex regex = new Regex(regularExpression, RegexOptions.Multiline);
//Will contain the found results
List<string> subStrings = new List<string>();

foreach (string str in testStrings)
{
  foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(str))
  {
    if (match.Success)
    {
      subStrings.Add(str.Replace(match.Groups[0].ToString(), string.Empty));
    }
  }
}
//Display the found results
foreach (string str in subStrings)
{
  Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

After executing this code, it will yield the following results:

```
for the sub 1 
for the sub 2 
for the sub 3
```

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this code makes it able to have different patterns after 'is:'.

**Edit:**
Hash Sling Slasher just provided the same answer, albeit a bit smaller :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Split` and `string.Join` like this ?

```
var str1 = "1.1)The Element is";
var str2 = "1.1)The Element is:(-) for the sub";

str2 = string.Join(" ",str2.Split().Take(str1.Count(x => x == ' ')+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

At least if your string is always with the same format ;)

```
string result = string.Join(" ", string1.Split(' ').Take(3).ToArray<string>());
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The following code should find the index of the first space after the length of string1.

```
int Length_Str1 = string1.Length;

string2 = string2.Remove(string2.IndexOf(' ', Length_Str1));
```

Please note that you should also add some checks to make sure that string2 is longer than string1 and that .IndexOf actually finds a space.