# Can I use string.Join (or an alternative) in .NET 3.x?

Tags: c#, string

I posted a question over here: 
[Selecting a substring from a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173610/selecting-a-substring-from-a-string-in-c-sharp) and I got a nice suggestion of using following code:

```
int index = String2.IndexOf(String1);
if(index >= 0)
{
    string result = String1;
    if (String1.Length < String2.Length)
    {
        string rest = String2.Substring(index + String1.Length);
        var chars = rest.TakeWhile(c => !Char.IsLetter(c) && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
        result = result + string.Join("", chars);
    }
}
```

I used it in .Net 4.0 and it's working fine. The problem is that I have to use .Net 3.0. Is there any way I can use `String.Join` in .NET 3.0 or .NET 3.5?

Comment: Are you sure? `System.Join` exist since .NET Framework 2.0 as far as I know. What is the values of `String2` and `String1`? What is your output and what do you expect?

Comment: [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.85).aspx) is a good place to start

Comment: The TakeWhile is probably the issue.

Comment: .Net 3.0? I never heard anyone use that. .Net 3.5 is more common, but that will have what you need. If you are missing Linq features take a look at LinqBridge or similar frameworks

Comment: @SonerGönül [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687788/string-join-in-net-3-5) in this they described that String.join does not exist in Dot Net 3.5

Comment: @Kami That *overload* doesn't exist in 3.5.  It only has an overload accepting an array.  Big difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET 3 there are only two overloads for [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so you need strings and you don't have LINQ.

Another way is not to use `String.Join` at all but for example a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < rest.Length; i++)
{
    char c = rest[i];                       
    bool takeChar = !Char.IsLetter(c) && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c);
    if (takeChar)
        sb.Append(c);
    else
        break;
}
result = result + sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Wouldn't that call the `String.Join(string, params object[])` one which was introduced in 4.0 too?

Comment: Similar functionality, but not exact. The call resulting above goes to `String.Join(string, string[])` because of the Select LINQ statement returns string values. The 4.0 call with params does not require a strongly-typed string array, and can take a comma-separated list of objects.

Comment: @Dirk: i have edited my answer to use a `StringBuilder` since LINQ   in .NET 3 is also a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know. I will give you a way to do it.

Convert your string in a StringBuilder in the System.Text namespace

Then do something like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(chars);
```

And pass your chars.

The result will be the same

Answer (score 0):

`String.Join` does work in .NET versions prior to 4.0 with the exception of the overloads taking an `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable<string>`.

In your code `chars` is an `IEnumerable<char>` so the method you use will be unavailable. You can use a different overload, for example

```
String.Join("", chars.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray());
```

which will use the [`String.Join(string, string[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) one.